# call_user_func_array() error in class-wp-hook.php

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, array

I have this message when I try to add a new variation of a product on Woocommerce/WP:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, array must have exactly two members in
>   /home/souffle/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288

This kind of message appears when I log into my admin account and other places too, since two days.

Can someone help me?

Comment: So somewhere in your code (theme, plugin) there is an incorrect usage of hook call... But it’s impossible to locate it based on the info you posted here, I’m afraid...